# Force parent div to adjust to its children size in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to encapsulate an input with an icon in it in a larger div. I'd like this div width to have exactly the size of the input.

Here is my code so far:

```
 <div>
    <input type="text">
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i>
 </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
div {
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
i {
    left: -30px;
    color: #fff;
}
input {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

With a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dwfh16me/3/

The problem here is that the div get the width of the input + the icon, even if the icon is in absolute position.
How can I make sure it doesn't take the icon width into account?

Mabny thanks

Answer (score 2):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/dwfh16me/4/

add `position:absolute` for `i` and for parent `position:relative`

```
i.glyphicon {
   position:absolute;
   right:6px;
   top:3px;
   color: #fff;
}
```